# Final Value Theorem Z Transform

Tags: control-theory, z-transform

This is probably really easy but I cannot see the wood for the trees.

I see the discrete time final value theorem given as:

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty}f[k] = \lim_{z\to 1} (z-1)F(z)$$

BUT also expressed as,

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty}f[k] = \lim_{z\to 1} (1-z^{-1})F(z)$$

But, 
$$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{z} = \frac{z-1}{z}$$

Not $z - 1$

Therefore they are not equivalent. Am I missing something here!?

I feel stupid asking the question. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As $z \rightarrow 1$

$$\dfrac{z-1}{z} \rightarrow \dfrac{z-1}{1} = z-1$$

**Update: Adding a proof of the final value theorem**

Start with the definition of the z-transform
$$F(z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N} f[k]z^{-k}$$
and also use the time advance theorem of the z-transform
$$z\left[F(z)-f[0]\right] = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N} f[k+1]z^{-k}$$
Now subtract the first from the second
$$(z-1)F(z) - zf[0] = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N} f[k+1]z^{-k}-f[k]z^{-k}$$
Then take the limit as $z \to 1$
$$\lim_{z \to 1} \space (z-1)F(z) - f[0] = \lim_{N \to \infty} \space f[N+1]-f[0]$$
so
$$\lim_{z \to 1} \space (z-1)F(z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \space f[N+1]=\lim_{N \to \infty} \space f[N]$$

**Alternately**

Using the time delay theorem of the z-transform
$$z^{-1}F(z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N} f[k-1]z^{-k}$$
we can get to
$$(1-z^{-1})F(z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N} f[k]z^{-k} -f[k-1]z^{-k}$$
and assuming $f[k] = 0$ for $k <0$ and taking the limit as $z\to1$
$$\lim_{z \to 1} \space (1-z^{-1})F(z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \space f[N]-f[-1] = \lim_{N \to \infty} \space f[N]$$

Comment: Yes, I kind of get that....

Comment: But as $\lim_{z\to 1}$ If we apply the same logic, surely we have $\frac{1-1}{1}$ dont we?

Comment: Sure, but in both cases as originally stated, the multiplier out front is 0.  In both cases the term out front "contributes" a zero at $z=1$.

Comment: According to _Signal_and_System_Analysis_, Chi-Tsong Chen, Saunders College Publishing, 1989 the $(z-1)F(z)$ version of the theorem requires $F(z)$ to be a "proper rational function" with all of its poles inside the unit circle.

Comment: Does the time advance theorem of  z-transform here refer to the 'time advance theorem of **one-sided**  z-transform'?